# Strange localization issue with ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, .net, exception, localization, internationalization

This "problem" will probably be hard to test/reproduce for someone whose Windows version is installed with English as the only language. I'm doing this on a Windows 7 machine installed with "Danish (Denmark)" (`"da-DK"` culture), .NET version 4.5.

I experience the following surprising behavior. The code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Now using intalled UI culture");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture;
Console.WriteLine(new ArgumentNullException().Message);
Console.WriteLine(new ArgumentOutOfRangeException().Message);

Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Now using invariant culture");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
Console.WriteLine(new ArgumentNullException().Message);
Console.WriteLine(new ArgumentOutOfRangeException().Message);
```

produces the following output:

```
Now using intalled UI culture
En værdi må ikke være null.
Det angivne argument lå uden for det gyldige værdiområde.

Now using invariant culture
Value cannot be null.
Det angivne argument lå uden for det gyldige værdiområde.
```

Explanation: In the first section, we see two localized exception messages as expected when the UI thread is Danish. But in the second section we see one English ("invariant") message, and one Danish message, even if the UI culture is not related to Danish anymore.

I tried this with a lot of other `mscorlib` exception classes as well, and it looks like only `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` does not respect the change of UI culture.

**Why is `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` different than other exceptions in this respect?**

(It would be interesting to hear if others (other versions of OS and Framework, and/or other languages) see the same behavior.)

PS! Pasting the following lines into PowerShell (which targets another .NET version) on the same machine gives the *opposite* problem with `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`?!

```
[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InstalledUICulture; New-Object ArgumentNullException;
[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InstalledUICulture; New-Object ArgumentOutOfRangeException;
[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture; New-Object ArgumentNullException;
[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture; New-Object ArgumentOutOfRangeException;
```

(Keep the long lines to make sure both statetments of each line are executed on the same thread by PowerShell.)

Comment: Update: I [reported this as a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/785717/system-argumentoutofrangeexception-incorrectly-caches-localized-message-text).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the source code of both exceptions you can see the problem fast. Here is the constructor of `ArgumentNullException`:

```
public ArgumentNullException() : 
           base(Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentNull_Generic")) {
    base.SetErrorCode(-2147467261);
}
```

As you can see the error message is loaded everytime out of the ressources. While the construcor of `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` looks like this:

```
public ArgumentOutOfRangeException() : base(RangeMessage) {
    base.SetErrorCode(-2146233086);
}
```

Where `RangeMessage` is a private static property:

```
private static string RangeMessage {
    get {
        if(_rangeMessage == null) {
            _rangeMessage = Environment.GetResourceString(
                                        "Arg_ArgumentOutOfRangeException");
        }
        return _rangeMessage;
    }
}
```

Here you can see is the problem the error message is cached. So it won't be updated. The only way I see is to access that `private static volatile string _rangeMessage;` with reflection and set it back to `null`.

Comment: Ah, this explains it beautifully. The reason why I was seeing the "opposite" behavior in PowerShell, was that I experimented a bit first, in the same shell, and happened to instantiate the first `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` with a thread with English language culture. The `static` cache field is used by all threads, no matter what their cultures are. When I open a "fresh" PowerShell application and paste in the four lines, I see the same behavior as with the C# application. This is a bug. The cache should not be kept when the current UI culture is different. Will report it as a bug.